# How to include jar lib in android extension?

Tags: android, haxe, openfl

I am building an extension that will use a jar file, I tried to include the jar files in the include.xml file like this:

```
<java path="pubnub/Pubnub-Android-3.6.3.jar" />
<java path="pubnub/bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar" />
```

But when I put the import in the java file:

```
import com.pubnub.api.*;
import org.json.*;
```

I get the error:

```
-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\Sam\Documents\GitHub\FoodDelivery\Car\bin\android\bin\deps\pubnubextenion\bin\classes
    [javac] C:\Users\Sam\Documents\GitHub\FoodDelivery\Car\bin\android\bin\deps\pubnubextenion\src\org\haxe\extension\PubnubExtenion.java:13: package com.pubnub.api does not exist
    [javac] import com.pubnub.api.*;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] 1 error
```

Any one can help?
Here is the files structure in this image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the directory dependencies/android/libs, put the files there and then use the include-tag in your xml.

Comment: Thanks, I've copied the jar files to dependencies/android/libs and it worked!, the strange thing is that I tried to remove the include-tags from my xml file, and it worked also!